# Windows 7 firewall and port forwarding from the router

Tags: windows-7, firewall

My home computer is behind the router provided by my ISP (Verizon FIOS). If I want to access it via remote desktop from work I forward Port 3389 on the router to internal IP address of the computer. There is no way to say at the router to only forward if request comes from specific IP (my work).

Can I filter out requests by IP via Windows 7 firewall? From what I see in Advanced Firewall Settings there is a way to filter out by IP address via "Scope". However, I am not sure if original external IP (my work) where request originated is passed by FIOS router to the computer.

Comment: I strongly recommend that if your router supports it, you choose a random public port for your RDP connection and forward it to port 3389 on your computer - say external port 34982 -> 3389. Because the RDP port 3389 is so well known, many hacking apps routinely scan IP address ranges looking for activity on 3389 and then bombard them with attempted logins or try to exploit vulnerabilities. Obscuring the port address helps avoid unwanted attention. Setting up a VPN link would be even better.

Comment: More expensive routers or routers with open source Tomato/ddwrt software will allow this. El Cheapo ones (aka the ones from the ISP) won't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With normal "port forwarding", your computer will see the same originating address.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a custom rule in Windows 7 Firewall you can indeed specify your remote IP and then allow access under Action. You will want to specify the protocol and port as well. This will effectively allow only inbound connections to that computer on the port specified from the specified IP.

I do however suggest you listen to Linker3000's comment and use a different incoming port on the router as well as this, just to be safe.